# Nutch is crawling only few links in a given domain

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

Problem occurs in Nutch 1.9 with ubuntu 12.04. I'm trying to crawl the links available in a website. I have given the website url in seed.txt file. I didn't make any changes to the default configuration except the http.agent.name (New) property and db.max.outlinks.per.page (-1). I'm using the following command to crawl 
`crawl urls test -depth 3` 
Crawler is supposed to crawl all the links available within the depth of 3. But only 5 links  are availble when I run the following linkdb command. All the five links are available in the home page

```
nutch readlinkdb test/linkdb -dump myoutput/out1<br/>
```

Did I miss any configuration changes? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Set number of url's to crawl in each level using `-topN`:

> bin/nutch crawl $URLS -dir $CRAWL_LOC -depth 3 -topN 1000

Answer (score 0):

In Nutch 1.10, db.ignore.internal.links defaults to true, which means that the link db will not contain internal links, only external. If you haven't changed the default setting, then the link db will not reflect the extent of the crawl. If you want it to contain these links, you can change the value of this property to false in your config file.

If you want to see all the links that were crawled, dump the crawl db. In 1.10 this is done via:

```
bin/nutch readdb MyCrawl/crawldb/ -dump crawlout
```

I'm not sure what the differences are between 1.9 and 1.10, but I imagine the commands are similar. (The 1.10 release notes don't indicate that the handling of internal links has changed.)